# Win10 Quick Access shared

Tags: windows-10

A customer finally switched to win10 and know has strange behavior regarding the Quick Access in Explorer.

The entries between some (not all) domain users are synchronized.
When user A pins something to his Quick Access it will appear in the Quick Access of user B only seconds later.
There are no MS-accounts involved, just domain accounts.

Any hints?

Comment: Are these problem users receiving a GPO that contains the following:
`User Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings\Folder Redirection\AppData(Roaming)` You can run `RSOP` to check. If they do, could you describe the full set of those redirection settings? Do you still want them to use folder redirection?

Comment: I think you are on to something. Will check. Thanks